# What is the best sentnce to write, which one is correct?

Tags: word-request, word-order

1- I can assist you (in) learning English or Arabic and helping you translate your documents to Arabic.

2- I can assist you to learn English or Arabic and help you translating your documents to Arabic.

Comment: #2 is better, but you don't assist **and** help.  Simplify: I can help you learn English or Arabic, and translate your documents into Arabic.

Comment: 'Helping' is redundant in the first version. "I can assist you in (a) learning English or Arabic and (b) translating your documents..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neither is quite right. In the first "helping you translate" implies you are assisting them in helping themselves, which is nonsense. In the second "assist you to" is definitely not right and "translating" should be just "translate" or "in translating"". Better would be ...

"I can assist you in/with learning English or Arabic and help you translate your documents to Arabic." - assist is a little clunky but not wrong.

"I can help you learn English or Arabic and (help you) translate your documents to Arabic." - without the second "help you" it flows better but may sound ambiguous depending on context.

"I can assist/help you in/with learning English or Arabic and translating your documents to Arabic."